# Finding which plugin uses cloudflare (due to GDPR)

Tags: plugins, cloudflare

after creating a wordpress homepage using quite a few existing plugins, due to the european GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) i now have to limit the calls of any external resource to a minimum.

Is there a good way to find out which plugin uses cloudflare ? Looking at the homepage direclty, the relevant code snippets are:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-css-css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css?ver=4.9.6" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js?ver=4.9.6"></script>
```

So its probably a plugin using the jquery-ui-timepicker. But i wonder if there is a good & fast way to find out which one.